# how to fix PyCharm python console prompt?

Tags: python, pycharm, console, command, prompt

Somehow python console's working ability is lost in my PyCharm.
In python console, Normally after  "enter" primary prompt >>> we get >>> next line.
In my case after "enter" primary prompt >>>, I am getting secondary prompts ...
I am unable to execute anything with the python console.
If I run code from a script they run fine.
I have checked Run >> Edit Configuration >> execution with all options nothing works.

[image]
Does anyone know why it happens and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to, but it kind of sounds like you have some long-running code being executed in a script holding the console up. Can you show an example of what prompt you're referring to?

Comment: Actually, `...` means the console is waiting for you to finish what you're writing. I'm guessing you missed a closing bracket or quote in your code.

Comment: I share a screenshot in my next answer, here I cannot inset the screenshot.

Comment: Just for reference, please post all information in your question, not as an answer. And the `...` means it's waiting for you to finish typing. I can't see why it would be, but I'd double check to make sure the `=` and `+` are proper characters, and not weird characters that your keyboard decided to use.

Comment: Try entering a `;` after the `...` and see what it says.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry I added a screenshot to the original post. I try entering ; still it's the same.

Comment: I'd double check the characters then to make sure they're proper characters and not weird ones confusing Pycharm. I've used Pycharm for a few years now, and every time I've got the behavior you're describing, I was missing a `)`, or I had pasted a weird character into the console.

Comment: thanks! In any case, at least it should work as a calculator e.g. >>> 2+3  return 5. I copy the same content and run it in the original python console it works fine. I am just wondering if some settings need to be enabled. It was working fine a few hours ago.